# Chat and UITable

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have two classes, class A and class B. Class A has a mission not related to chat BUT it needs to react to the arrive of a chat message. When a message arrives, it is stored in a NSMutableDictionary, being that dictionary stored in a NSMutableArray. If the message received is the first one ([array count]==1), class B view is displayed, presenting an UITableView, wich data is populated with the array. Everything works perfectly for the fierst message.

A second message arrives. The new message is added to the array (that is done in class A) but, the table is not populated. How could i achieve that goal?

The code:

Class A

```
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];

NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
[m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];
[messarray addObject:m];


[self newMessageReceived:messarray];
}

- (void)xmppStreamDidAuthenticate:(XMPPStream *)sender
{
NSLog(@"Method xmppStreamDidAuthenticate");
[self goOnline];
}

//- (void) newMessageReceived:(NSMutableDictionary *)message
-(void) newMessageReceived:(NSMutableArray *)messarraylocal
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];//An static class to store settings like username, and other things that must be available in the hole app.
general.numcels++;
general.messarray=messarraylocal;
  // NSString *firstmessage=[message objectForKey:@"msg"];
//NSString *from=[message objectForKey:@"sender"];    
//NSArray *listItems = [from componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
//NSString *fromsplit=[listItems objectAtIndex:0];
//general.firstmess=firstmessage;
//general.firstfrom=fromsplit;




if ([messarraylocal count]==1){
ChatViewController *cvc=[[ChatViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Chat" bundle:nil];

[[self navigationController]pushViewController:cvc animated:YES];

}
}
```

Class B:

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];
NSLog(@"We are in numberOfRowsInSection, de ChatViewController");
return general.messarray.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];

NSLog(@"We are in cellForRowAtIndexPath de ChatViewController");
//UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
//if(!cell){
messarray=general.messarray;
for (int i=0;i<messarray.count; i++)
{
    diccio=[messarray objectAtIndex:i];
    general.firstmess=[diccio objectForKey:@"msg"];
    general.firstfrom=[diccio objectForKey:@"sender"];

UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
//}
text=general.firstmess;
remite=general.firstfrom;
[[cell textLabel]setText:remite];
[[cell detailTextLabel] setText:text];

return cell;

}
}

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
{
NSString *msg = [[message elementForName:@"body"] stringValue];
NSString *from = [[message attributeForName:@"from"] stringValue];
NSLog(@"We are in didReceiveMessage of ChatViewController");
NSMutableDictionary *m = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[m setObject:msg forKey:@"msg"];
[m setObject:from forKey:@"sender"];


[self newMessageReceived:m];
}

- (void) newMessageReceived: (NSMutableDictionary *) message// this method is NEVER called
{
General *general = [General sharedManager];
general.numcels++;
NSLog(@"numcels vale %i", general.numcels);
NSString *firstmessage=[message objectForKey:@"msg"];
NSString *from=[message objectForKey:@"sender"];    
NSArray *listItems = [from componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"];
NSString *fromsplit=[listItems objectAtIndex:0];
general.firstmess=firstmessage;
general.firstfrom=fromsplit;
NSLog(@"Message receive in ChatViewController: %@ from %@", [message objectForKey:@"msg"], fromsplit);

}
```

In the method didViewLoad of class B, i do:

```
table.delegate=self;
table.dataSource=self;
```

But with no result. I know that [table reload] could work but... where can i do it?

Anybody can help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class A `newMessageReceived` after you add the new message to the global `messarray`

You will need to fire an `NSNotification`

```
-(void) newMessageReceived:(NSMutableArray *)messarraylocal
{
    //in addition to your normal code, add the following
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NewMessage" object:nil];
}
```

Now in Class B register for observation

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    //In addition to your normal code here add the following
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(newMessage) name:@"NewMessage" object:nil];
}

//Add this method that will call reload data
- (void) newMessage
{
    [table reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Omar im just about to exit work and maybe I will not have time to test your solution, but I promise that if monday i test and it works, i will upvote your answer. But even if it doesn't works, thank you very much for spending time trying to help :)

Comment: its always a pleasure to help :)

Comment: I have tried, Omar, and it does call reloadData. But, it does not runs the "for" properly. It returns the same cell, and never returns the second one in the array. But, your answer was correct. Thank you again!

Comment: You are welcome, if you have additional issues add new question, ill be right at it :)

Comment: I think im going to abuse of you and ask a new question :P

Comment: hehe we are here to answer after all :D

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/11079561/chat-loading-the-same-messages-in-all-cells there is the question

Answer (score 0):

Are you storing the previous message in you array...
if not then in your **didReceiveMessage:** put one line before adding the object in array...

```
[messarray removeAllObjects];
```